# No previous output,but header redirect doesn't work in PHP

Tags: php, header

```
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

I've checked that there is no previous output:

```
ob_start();

...
var_dump(ob_get_contents());
ob_flush();
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

outputs:

```
string '' (length=0)
```

Then why does the redirect fail?

Though I see lots of warnings and notices in the `error_log`,but that doesn't affect `header()` as long as it doesn't output anything to the browser,right?

**UPDATE**

Some logs(should not be related though):

```
[Wed May 19 00:26:10 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\\Works\\general
[Wed May 19 00:26:10 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/cookie_usage.php
[Wed May 19 00:26:10 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() D:\\Works\\login.php:0, referer: http://localhost/cookie_usage.php
[Wed May 19 00:26:10 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   2. tep_redirect() D:\\Works\\login.php:33, referer: http://localhost/cookie_usage.php
```

Comment: Depends, maybe you can show the warnings?

Comment: $url is empty. Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.

Comment: Are you sure the $url isn't empty?

Comment: I'm sure,in fact the same code can work on production environment.

Comment: You just have to check it, with your own eyes. Not telling everyone it works on another server. I am going to vote to close this question for being not a real one

Comment: @user198729: Have you checked the headers received by the browser to see if a Location header is being sent and what value it is being set to?

Comment: Location header is not sent ,checked in firebug.

Answer (score 3):

ob_flush() sends to the output buffer. (prints what is in the OB)
That is considered output. 
you may want to use ob_clean()

it is also good practice to use 
exit() or die() after a header('location ...') call.

Also note that whitespace at the end of the file will do this.

For the most part I never use ?> at the end of a PHP file anymore, just leave it open

?> is optional anyway.

Comment: He's only using ob here to test for output.

Comment: I didn't realize that, however it is a solution to the problem; Use ob to capture the output and ob_clean() and the redirect should work, otherwise there may be whitespace outside of <?php tags somewhere

Comment: I also tried `ob_clean()` before `header`,not working.And the url is valid.

Comment: try doing a header('location: http://www.google.com'); exit(); instead and see what happens. If it redirects, something in your header redirect is bad, otherwise you do have output going on somewhere. Maybe its in an included or required file. Could you maybe put the entire php file on pastie.org (or similar) for us?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue before few days. There was extra white space in the end of php included file which I was calling before header function. I removed that white space and it starter working for me.

Answer (score -3):

> that doesn't affect header() as long
>   as it doesn't output anything to the
>   browser,right?

wrong.

Comment: Because you have to read the error message, not sitting and guessing all day! If it's header's problem there ought to be an error message. To be cartain, what is wrong. Playing with output buffering is just wrong way.

Comment: I'm not guessing and I check error logs frequently,but this time it really doesn't help!

Comment: @user if there is no header error, there is **not a single reason** to play with ob_start. It must be sensible action, based on some reason (an error message). So, if you check your buffering without a reasom, I call it guessing. Because you *guess* there is some header error, not knowing it. Now you have to check the $url variable and code logic - if this header get ever executed

Comment: I saw it got executed by step-by-step debug,but somehow there is no Location header in the response.

Comment: @user that seems very strange. You have tp double check for the "Headers already sent" error. You may be need to lower errorl_reporting to warning level